# Copy and Raname File in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to copy file

> base.txt

To Other Folders  And I want his name change To The Folder Name.

```
cd c:\Program\Levels
copy-item *.txt c:\Books -force -recurse
Get-ChildItem C:\Books -Filter *.txt -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Directory.Name}
```

So he's copying *.txt for the folder 'Books' and renaming the file to 'books.txt' but, he did not copy the file to subfolders within 'Books'

I want it to copy the .txt for subfolders in 'Books' and rename the .txt to the folder name.

Obs: the .txt file is unique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the file `base.txt` which is presumably some sort of template will be copied to each subfolder in `C:\Books`? I think I can understand your logic approach but I offer this as a solution instead.

```
$templateFile = "C:\temp\base.txt"
Get-ChildItem "C:\Books" | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer} |ForEach-Object{
    $newName = "{0}\{1}.txt" -f $_.FullName, $_.Name
    Copy-Item -Path $templateFile -Destination $newName
}
```

Gather each subdirectory of "C:\Books" and in each of those directories copy the file `base.txt` to its new location where its name is the name of the parent folder.

Comment: @Jones in order for me to help you you need to be more specific. What is the exact error you are getting.

Comment: Hummm...i think "{0}\{1}.txt"..He is reading this part as text

Comment: Think of me ... Inside the folder c : \ Books exist three subfolders . Within subfolders , there are five subfolders . I just need to copy the first three subfolders . The file name must be the name of the folder.

Comment: @Jones I made an edit. It will only work on the subfolders of c:\books

Comment: with " -directory " it does not work . When I remove the " -directory " it works , however it creates the file with the name out of the subfolders . Is everything in c : \ Books 
Current : C : \ Books \ Bus.txt
Correct: C: \ Books \ Bus \ Bus.txt .

The BUS folder already exists .

Comment: @Jones I'm guessing you only have PowerShell 2.0. I replaced the `-Directory` with something that would work. Please try again and let me know. Are the files to be created supposed to be in C:\books or the folders?

Comment: He is still creating the files and left inside the folder C : \ Books .
BUS.TXT
CAR.TXT
BIKE.TXT
I want these files to be created or moved into subfolders BUS , CAR and BIKE that already exist .
BUS.TXT into C : \ Books \ BUS \
CAR.TXT into C : \ Books \ CAR \
etc ...

Comment: @Jones OK. that should work now like you expect it to. That was my mistake.

Comment: EXCELENT JOB MATT!!!!! THANK YOU!!!! THANK THANK THANK YOU! EXCELENT! WORKED!!!!!!!!!